# Adjusted insert implementation in dictionary

Tags: haskell

Having the following dictionary implementation in Haskell:

```
module TreeDict (Dict, empty, insert, lookup) where       

import Prelude hiding(lookup)                                               

data Dict k v = Empty | Node { key :: k, val :: v, left :: Dict k v, right :: Dict k v }
    deriving (Eq, Show)                                                     

empty :: Dict k v                                                           
empty = Empty                                                               

insert :: (Ord k) => k -> v -> Dict k v -> Dict k v                         
insert k v Empty = Node k v empty empty                                     
insert k v d                                                                
        | k < key d = Node (key d) (val d) (insert k v (left d)) (right d)  
        | k > key d = Node (key d) (val d) (left d) (insert k v (right d))  
        | otherwise = Node k v (left d) (right d)                           

lookup :: (Ord k) => k -> Dict k v -> Maybe v                               
lookup k Empty = Nothing                                                    
lookup k d                                                                  
        | k < key d = lookup k (left d)                                     
        | k > key d = lookup k (right d)                                    
        | otherwise = Just (val d)
```

I would like to write a function similar to insert that would allow me to keep as a value how many times a given key has been inserted to a tree (but with `Ord k` class only).

For example: for a list [aa, bb, aa, aa] my dictionary would keep: {aa -> 3, bb -> 1}.

Any idea how I can adjust my code?

Comment: Are you wanting the value at that node to be the `Int` count, or do you want to store it as metadata on each node?

Comment: @bheklilr I would like to keep `Int` as value.

Comment: I would recommend writing a function `insertOrUpdate :: Ord k => k -> (Maybe v -> v) -> Dict k v -> Dict k v` where the function provided as the second argument operates on the output of `lookup`.  If the key doesn't exist, then `lookup` returns `Nothing`, so your updating function can return a default, otherwise it returns a new value based on the old one.  An example usage would be something like `insertOrUpdate "aa" (\v -> case v of { Nothing -> 1; Just v' -> v' + 1 }) mydict` but formatted prettier.

Comment: You can implement it naively at first, then I would recommend attempting a more efficient implementation that won't have to perform separate `lookup` and `insert` operations.  Get it working, then get it fast.

Comment: You know there's `Data.Map` right? If so, take a look at [this implementation](https://github.com/Jefffrey/Solidran/blob/master/src/Solidran/List.hs#L17) of that algorithm with `Data.Map` and port it to your `Dict`.

Comment: @bheklilr Thanks a lot! It looks like your comment can help me.